# Having problems with constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to java and trying to create a simple code checking the gas usage of a given car with given miles per gallon and gas but every time I try to initialize the variables, it keeps giving me errors. inTank and mpg say that only final is permitted and the constructors can't initialize the variable parameters for some reason. If someone could explain to me why and how to fix this I would be grateful. Happens in the Udacity IDE and Ecclipse.

```
public class MileagePrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // your code here
        private double inTank;
        private double mpg;

        public MileagePrinter(double gasInTank, double milesPerGallon) {
        inTank = gasInTank;
        mpg = milesPerGallon;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is there a constructor inside your `main()` method?

Comment: The constructor and variables should be outside the main function and in the scope of the class.

Comment: You are not having problems with your constructor; you are having problems with the basic syntactic structure of java source code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Reorder the code... you have class variables and a constructor inside the main method...

it must look like

```
public class MileagePrinter {
 private double inTank;
 private double mpg;

 public MileagePrinter(double gasInTank, double milesPerGallon) {
      inTank = gasInTank;
      mpg = milesPerGallon;
 }

public static void main(String[] args){

            // your code here

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Main` method and `constructor` are different from each other. `Main` is the starting point of execution of a program whereas `constructor` is used to create an object. We need to take `constructor` out of `main` method here, e.g.

```
public class MileagePrinter {
    private double inTank;
    private double mpg;

    public MileagePrinter(double gasInTank, double milesPerGallon) {
        inTank = gasInTank;
        mpg = milesPerGallon;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MileagePrinter pointer = new MileagePrinter(10d, 100d); //create object using constructor           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to separate the main in a class Main (for example, the name isn't important) for an organization of this type:

main.java :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

MileagePrinter.java :

```
public class MileagePrinter {
    private double inTank;
    private double mpg;

    public MileagePrinter(double gasInTank, double milesPerGallon) {
        inTank = gasInTank;
        mpg = milesPerGallon;
    }
}
```